# How to emit a result from javascript code to all users connected using socket.io

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I saw this js code online and i modified the best my knowledge to make it not only visible to current user but all users:

```js
var textarea = $('#textarea');
var typingStatus = document.querySelector('#typing_on');
var lastTypedTime = new Date(0); // it's 01/01/1970
var typingDelayMillis = 2000; // how long user can "think about his spelling" before we show "No one is typing -blank space." message

function refreshTypingStatus() {
    if (!textarea.is(':focus') || textarea.val() == '' || new Date().getTime() - lastTypedTime.getTime() > typingDelayMillis) {
        socket.emit('stat', typingStatus.innerHTML = 'no type');
    } else {
        socket.emit('stat', typingStatus.innerHTML = 'User typing....');
    }
}
function updateLastTypedTime() {
    lastTypedTime = new Date();
}

setInterval(refreshTypingStatus, 100);
textarea.keypress(updateLastTypedTime);
textarea.blur(refreshTypingStatus);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        
            <input name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5">

            <div id="typing_on"></div>
    </body>
```

What i did in front end is add socket.emit to the result as seen above and i did equivalent to that in back-end (server.js)

but it doens't work and show like this:

[image]

**what i want is for the 'user typing' to appear in both sides (clients)**
How can i do that?

Comment: You need to understand [Socket.IO broadcasting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_broadcasting.htm)

Comment: Hmm maybe I should do the reverse

Answer (score 0):

To send message from client to server and then sending the message to all clients connected to the websocket:

**server.js**

```
io.on('connect', socket => {
  let counter = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    socket.emit('hello', ++counter);
  }, 1000);
});
```

**Index.html**

```
const socket = io();

socket.on('connect', () => {
  $events.appendChild(newItem('connect'));
});

socket.on('hello', (counter) => {
  $events.appendChild(newItem(`hello - ${counter}`));
});
```

If you want to send message to all clients except the person who is sending the message, use **broadcast** instead of **emit**

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with your backend WebSocket code. Because your frontend code is working correctly for the person who is actually typing the message. I checked it by replacing socket.emit with console.log. Check JsFiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/65eLatpj/ so it would be easy to figure out the bug if you provide the part of your backend WebSocket code.